# Azure Application Insights not working on Sitecore 9.1 PaaS

Tags: azure, paas, application-insights

I've provisioned a Sitecore 9.1 PaaS, and for some odd reason the **Application Insights** is not loading graphics except in **Live Metrics Stream** for Process CPU data

[image]

[image]

I went through the existing post [Accessing log files in application insights for Sitecore 9 in Azure app service](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/13863/accessing-log-files-in-application-insights-for-sitecore-9-in-azure-app-service) and did the following

1. **Check appinsights.instrumentationkey ConnectionStrings.config**

[image: Connection Strings AppInsights]

2. **Check the Daily Cap**
   It was 0.33, then I raised to 2GB for testing purposes
   [image: Daily Cap]

Another thing is that the **Search** shows results from Sitecore

[image]

3. **Check showconfig.aspx**
   [image: Showconfig]
4. **Enable Live Metrics Stream** - Only shows CPU data
   [image: Enable Live Metrics Stream]
5. **Enable Application map** - I removed the comment line, and restart the Application, waited for 5 minutes and still no data
   [image: ApplicationMap]
6. **Querying Application Insights** - It works
   [image: QueryingAppInsights]

Comment: Do you have ApplicationInsights added to web.config as well? it needs to be added to trace listener and there is also a handler.

Comment: @BartłomiejMucha could you be more specific about "ApplicationInsights added to web.config" and "added to trace listener", and "there is also a handler"?

Comment: For example in Web.config under `<system.webServer><modules>` there should be `ApplicationInsightsWebTracking` module added. Also under <system.diagnostics><trace><listeners>` there should be `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TraceListener.ApplicationInsightsTraceListener, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TraceListener` added

Comment: I do have a `<remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />`, and in the next line `<add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule,.... />`. And I do have `<add name="myAppInsightsListener" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TraceListener.ApplicationInsightsTraceListener, ... />`

Comment: in point 6., can you also query "requests" to see if you have any?

Comment: and on the first image, with charts for failed requests etc. can you change time range for the last 30 days and see

Comment: Nothing shows up when query for requests and no data for the last 30 days

Comment: ok looks like it does not store requests at all, that's why the charts with failed requests etc. are empty. Can check in the ApplicationInsights.config file, if there is a `<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.RequestTrackingTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.Web">` added

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91072/discussion-between-vinicius-deschamps-and-bartlomiej-mucha).

Comment: You can also use Sitecore 9.1 Update-1 to fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have raise this problem to the [Sitecore Support](https://support.sitecore.net/helpdesk/) which generated **a ticket #527731** (**`Please use this ticket# if you have the same issue`**)

### IMPORTANT: The following approach does not work without the hotfix provided by Sitecore, don't give a shot by simply changing the files specified in the step"after the hotfix has been installed"

Accordingly to the Sitecore response

> Be aware that the hotfix was built specifically for Sitecore XP 9.1
>   Initial Release, and you should not install it on other Sitecore
>   versions or in combination with other hotfixes, unless explicitly
>   instructed by Sitecore Support.
>
> Note that you need to extract ZIP file contents to locate installation
>   instructions and related files inside it.
>
> Unless stated differently in the installation instructions, the hotfix
>   should be installed on CM instance and then synced with other
>   instances using your regular development practices

The hotfix should be installed as a package, and will replace the following DLL libraries:

•   **/bin/Microsoft.AI.Web.dll**

•   **/bin/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.dll**

•   **/bin/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TraceListener.dll**

•   **/bin/Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation.dll**

•   **/bin/System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll**

After the hotfix has been installed these steps must be taken

1. Edit ApplicationInsights.config. Under the ApplicationInsights\TelemetryModules paste the following line at the bottom of the section

   `<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.AspNetDiagnosticTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />`

   2. Edit web.config. Under the configuration/system.webServer/modules after `<remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking"/>`, insert the following string:

`<add name="TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule" type="Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation.TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule, Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation"  preCondition="integratedMode,managedHandler"/>`

Once you modify the files, restart the App Services and try to access it again to generate data for the Application Insights

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is also a bug in Sitecore 9.1 update 1. I have raised it as a ticket with Sitecore support and they have provided a bug reference **291373**. Development of the hotfix is in progress.

I note that in the hotfix mentioned above, 2 of the files are not present in the /bin folder of 9.1.1. The missing files are:

- /bin/Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation.dll
- /bin/System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll

Comment: Sitecore have released Hotfix 339049 specifically for 9.1 update 1. Tested and working in my installation.

Answer (score -1):

It's a bug in 9.1.

To fix this you need:

Add telemetry module to ApplicationInsights.config

```
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.AspNetDiagnosticTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
```

Add module to web.config under system.webserver

```
<add name="TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule" type="Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation.TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule, Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation" 
        preCondition="integratedMode,managedHandler" />
```

Comment: I just did what you said, and YSOD shows up `Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`